# angular rxjs pipe remove element from array

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a service with a delete function. The delete function will call an api and it will return true or false. When true, I will lookup the index in my array, splice it and return the new array. So for example

```
private items = [];
onItemDeleted  = new Subject<any>();

  delete(id:number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete('http://my.api.com/item/' + id)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(checkServerSuccessResponse),
        map(data => {
            const index1  = this.items.findIndex((element) => {
              return element.id === id;
            });
            if (index1 >= 0 ) {
              this.items.splice(index1,1);
            }
            this.onItemDeleted.next(this.items);
            return this.items;
          }
        ),
        catchError(returnFalse),
      );
  }
```

I have a helper for the switchmap :

```
export function checkServerSuccessResponse(data: Response): Observable<any> {
    return (data && data['success'] === true) ? of(data) : throwError("server responded false");
}
```

Although this works, I have a feeling the map section can reformatted. I first thought of filter (after the switchmap) to exclude the element with the id I've supplied, then emit the new array, but then I realised, the filter is not subscribed to the this.items array.

What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: I don't know you other code, for example where `this.items` coming from, why do you publish updated items to `onItemDeleted`. But I would probably: a) pass `this.items` to `delete` method also like `delete(id, items)` because on the time when response will arrive, you don't know what will happen with `this.items`; b) that thing within the `map`, move to separate function, that will be `removeById(items, id)`; c) `pipe` will become `switchMap(checkServerSuccessResponse), map(removeById), tap(onItemDeleted.next), catchError(returnFalse)` (calls abbreviated to fit to this comment).

Comment: Moving the logic for the delete in removeById function that is what I also want. But what I dont understand is the map(removeById). Because in the stack of the pipe, the first argument is the response from the api call (checkServerSuccessResponse helper) and not the this.items array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know you other code, for example where `this.items` coming from, why do you publish updated items to `onItemDeleted`. But I would probably: a) pass `this.items` to delete method also like `delete(id, items)` because on the time when response will arrive, you don't know what will happen with `this.items`; b) that thing within the map, move to separate function, that will be `removeById(items, id)`; c) simplify `pipe`. Like this:

```
private items = [];
onItemDeleted  = new Subject<any>();

  removeById(fromItems, id) {
    const index1  = fromItems.findIndex((element) => {
      return element.id === id;
    });
    if (index1 >= 0 ) {
      fromItems.splice(index1,1);
    }
    return fromItems;
  }

  // who ever calls this, should provide copy of items also
  // then you will be kinda protected from concurrent
  // modification, when http response complete, but this.items
  // is completely different, from when http request started
  delete(fromItems, id:number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete('http://my.api.com/item/' + id)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(checkServerSuccessResponse),
        map(data => this.removeById(fromItems, id)),
        tap(items => this.onItemDeleted.next(items)),
        catchError(returnFalse),
      );
  }
```

Comment: ugh .. makes so sense right now .. I was to stuck to map the function directly to the removebyid function.

Comment: `pipe` is great to express what you want to do, if possible with one liners, becomes much more readable :)

Comment: hehe yes .. thank you .. I was so stuck in my mind .. got it working now, even as a global helper function :)